# How can I insert a element in a STL vector matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, stl

I'm writing a code for create a adjacency_matrix using STL vector class

My matrix is this:

```
vector<vector<float> > adjacency_matrix;
```

I need to know how can I insert new values in the matrix, similar to v[x][y] = z

I try this code, but it fails:

```
    adjacency_matrix.insert((adjacency_matrix.begin()+node1).begin()+node2,distance);
```

Example

I have this

`0   []   7   9
2.6   0   []  3.5
[]   []    0  []
[]   []   []   0`

Then, I have to insert 12.5 value in (3,2) position
The result must be this:

`0   []   7   9
2.6   0   []  3.5
[]   []    0  []
[]   12.5   []   0`

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting elements into 2D vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241177/inserting-elements-into-2d-vector)

Comment: You first have to create an item in the outer vector to be able to insert values in the inner.

Comment: @vidhu-gangvar No duplicate: I want to add a new element in a determinated position, no only add this

Comment: @AlmuHs: In that case, you need to initialize vector first with some default values: `vector<vector<float>> matrix(10, vector<float>(10, 0.0))`. You can also try std::map if you don't want to do that.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ How can I do this?

Comment: @AlmuHS: It's not clear what exactly should be the result of the operation you want to perform. Give an example of the matrix's contents before and after the "insertion" operation.

Comment: @MichałGóral How can I initialize the matrix?

Comment: @AlmuHS: I redacted my previous answer, because I pressed enter to early. :)

Comment: @AlmuHS post minimal, complete verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector` is continuous, resizable array of values. You can't access its x-th element if it wasn't previously initialized altogether with elements before it. This would be undefined behaviour.

So you should create the whole matrix beforehand like that:

```
size_t m_size = 10;
std::vector<std::vector<float>> matrix(m_size, std::vector<float>(m_size, 0.0));
matrix[1][3] = 1.0;
std::cout << matrix[0][0]; // 0.0
std::cout << matrix[1][3]; // 1.0

// still BAD, because we initialized only matrix of size 10; we could, however, expand it e.g. with vector::push_back
matrix[13][0] = 2; // UB: crash
```

If you can't do that, you could use `std::map`, which creates default elements automatically when `operator[]` is called (note however that map is actually a tree, and `operator[]` performs a logarithmic search instead of vector's constant access):

```
std::map<size_t, std::map<size_t, float>> matrix;
matrix[0][1] = 3.0;
std::cout << matrix[0][0];  // 0.0
std::cout << matrix[0][1];  // 3.0
```

If uninitialized values are indeterminate, you can express that with e.g. `std::optional`:

```
std::map<size_t, std::map<size_t, std::optional<float>>> matrix;
matrix[0][1] = 5.0;
std::cout << matrix[0][0].value_or(127.0); // 127.0
std::cout << *(matrix[0][1]); // 5.0

if (matrix[14][27])
    std::cout << *(matrix[14][27]);
else
    std::cout << "not initialized";
```

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment you need to initialize your "matrix" first. Than you can access the elements.
But beware that you should instert into the inner vector not in the "matrix". In addition begin() returns an iterator which needs to be accesesed with `->`.
If your "matrix" is initialized properly you can also use the `[]` for acces, which is more usable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<float>> test(10,vector<float>(10));

    int x=1;
    int y=2;
    //access via iterator
    auto inner_it =test.begin()+x;
    inner_it->insert(inner_it->begin()+y,2.0);
    cout<<test[x][y]<<"\n";
    // access via []
    test[y][x]=3;
    cout<<test[y][x];
    return 0;
}
```

Depending on what you want, it is better to use an Linear Algebra library (e.g. Eigen).

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what will be the future lenght of the matrix, so I can't be secure that this are fully initialized

Comment: You might be asking a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/xy-problem/info). What do you want to archieve with your matrix? Maybe you need a [Sparse Matrix](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__SparseQuickRefPage.html).

Comment: It's a Graph's adjacency matrix.
I need it for implement TSP algorithms